# not-quite-honest public service

Tags: nouns, idioms, pejorative-language

In a noun or idiom, what are public servants who only seek public office for the sake of income called?

Comment: Politicians? --

Comment: It's not quite the same thing but one distinction that might be useful is that between "career politicians" (who see it mainly as a job) and "ideological politicians" (who are in it in order to bring about specific changes).

Comment: *Highbinder* had that meaning, but it's pretty much obsolete now, so probably not of much use unless you're writing an historical novel in just the right era; after it referred specifically to one gang, and before it died out. I might call such a person "a Haughey" but your politics and/or frame of reference may vary.

Comment: Your question as stated does not correspond to its title. In your question you speak of personal gain (income). In the title you speak of dishonesty. These are not the same thing. Please correct one or the other or both, so they fit better.

Comment: [Probable duplicate](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Comment: In support of _politicians_ above: here in the UK at least, no one really gets much of an income in public office - certainly not to the extent that they would choose it rather than simply being a manager, banker or laywer who was merely in it for the paycheck.

Rather, it is typically through subsidiary opportunities such as the sale of public assets or the creation of laws or regulations which benefit organisations in which the individual has a current or future financial interest.

Answer (score 1):

I think [bureaucrat](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Bureaucrat) used in a derogatory sense may suggest the idea you are putting forward:

> an official who works by fixed routine without exercising intelligent judgment.
>   [1835–45; < French bureaucrate. See -crat]

Answer (score 1):

[Placeman](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/placeman) (or placewoman, presumably), though it has an archaic feel, may be making a comeback.

Answer (score 1):

In economics, a ***[rent-seeker](http://www.econlib.org/library/Enc/RentSeeking.html)*** is one who extracts income from *rents* in the economic sense of the word: to increase one's own wealth parasitically, i.e. by manipulating political structures rather than conducting economic transactions— extracting value from others without yourself creating value. One must of course clarify that the *rent-seeker* is not a mere landlord. (And *rentier*, while also related to economic rents, is a separate concept as well).

Typically, the term is applied to firms (e.g. [patent trolls](http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB10001424052702303292204577514782932390996), cartels), labor unions, or gangsters who lobby the government to artificially restrict competition, but it can also be applied to dishonest bureaucrats who use their power over licenses, permits, or other official approvals to extract favors, preferences, or even [kickbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kickback_%28bribery%29).

Some of the other terms suggested in other answers may be applicable; however, they are mainly used with appointed or career officials as opposed to elected ones.

If the official's motivation is not corruption but indifference— he or she took the job to collect a salary while doing as little work as possible, with no interest in the purpose of the job or the larger mission of the organization— *bureaucrat* as suggested by Josh61 would suffice. But *bureaucrat* has many other connotations— obstructionism, inflexibility, pettifoggery— that may not be applicable.

If the official is not necessarily corrupt but unqualified, then he or she is a *[placeman](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/placeman)*, as TimLymington suggests. If the official is given a job that requires no work, he or she is holding a *[sinecure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinecure)*, and likely to be a beneficiary of *[cronyism](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cronyism)*.

Answer (score 0):

[Grafter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grafter), [grifter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grifter), or possibly [barrator](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/barrator), though the last is little known outside translations and discussions of Dante’s *Inferno* (eighth circle, fifth *bolgia,* Cantos [21](http://www.online-literature.com/dante/inferno/21/)–23), where barrators are punished in a manner that has become stereotypical of the punishments of Hell (flying demons with pitchforks tormenting sinners swimming in boiling pitch).

Answer (score 0):

On a more neutral tone, it could be an `uncommitted public servant`. (This rather describes the fact that public good is not their prior objective). `"Uncommited staff"` seems to be in use more generally.

Answer (score 0):

*Careerist* is one term that comes to mind.  Another, but which is more general, is *opportunist*.

(But I've been chagrined to hear people use these terms **positively** lately. Part of the *greed is good* ideology, perhaps...)

Answer (score -1):

Corrupt. No-one who genuinely believes in public service goes into it for the money. Even if they end up in a high-paid job.

Comment: I can imagine a local government official who leans toward laziness, who sought office because they thought being county auditor would be an easy paycheck – yet that person would not be _corrupt_. In the context of politics, _corrupt_ often implies some sort illegal activity, such as embezzling money, or accepting bribes, or abusing power. Not every lazy ***paper-pusher*** at the Dept of Motor Vehicles is "corrupt."

Comment: Fair point. "Corrupt" might be too strong.

Comment: From an idealistic perspective, there's a somewhat philosophical truth to what you are saying: _"Why take the taxpayers money, when you don't have the heart to truly serve them?"_ But, realistically – alas! – I'm afraid that's not the way all government officials think or behave.